Is it possible to create a LUKS-encrypted file as Linux root and dd it to a physical partition later?
I am planning to install Linux into a file mounted as a loop device and formatted with ext4 file system, then transfer with dd to an actual physical partition at a later date.
I am wondering if it would be possible to encrypt the file with LUKS and then mount it via dm-mapper before creating the file system and installing the OS. Would that file transfer with dd to a physical partition and still work? (I will obviously have the fstab, crypttab, and the root bootloader parameters adjusted for the physical partition later...)
Thanks!

Yes, it would work. There's nothing particular about encryption that binds it to a specific device.
